# TableView não atualiza

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

estou com uma tableview com vários horários, portanto o usuário poderia confirmar que consumiu o remédio em um dos horários em questão, ate ai tudo bem, só que eu precisava atualizar a tableview após a confirmação do usuário e remover esse horário da listagem, tentei da seguinte forma porém sem êxito. Alguém sabe me explicar o pq não esta atualizando e uma forma para conseguir atualizar esses dados

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    if indexPath.section == 1{
        let confirmar = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Já Tomei") { action, index in

            self.confirmaTomouDoseMedicamento((self.arrayNotificacoesAtrasadas[indexPath.row].id))
            self.arrayNotificacoesAtrasadas.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        confirmar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        return [confirmar]
    }

    return nil
}
func confirmaTomouDoseMedicamento(idNotificacao: Int){
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let contexto: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    NotificacaoDAO().confirmaDosagem(contexto, idNotificacao: idNotificacao)
}
```

Comment: Tente colocar o self.tableView.reloadData() fora do if.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, 
não sei se já conseguiu resolver, para atualizar a table view utilize  o método reloadData().

Por exemplo:

```
self.minhatableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitua .Normal por .Destructive no style:

```
let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
    self.confirmaTomouDoseMedicamento((self.arrayNotificacoesAtrasadas[indexPath.row].id))
    self.arrayNotificacoesAtrasadas.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```